# bash shell awk count probability and output

Tags: bash, shell, awk

example file:

```
1 book book
      1 book is
      1 book This
      1 is book
      2 is is
      1 is pen
      2 is This
```

I want print `$1/(sum of $1 with the same $2),$2,$3`

the result should be:

```
1/3 book book
1/3 book is
1/3 book This
1/6 is book
2/6 is is.....etc
```

Here 's `awk` script and i want to find how to rewrite it to achieve my goal

```
{
count[$2]+=$1
}
END{for(elem in count) print $1/count[elem],count[elem],$3}
```

Comment: python would be better suited to this task, you need to scan file twice - once to compute counts and second time to print stats, and don't think that old awk can do this

Comment: @csharpfolk It can, look at my answer.

Comment: @123 you passed file to process twice, nice solution - like it

Comment: @csharpfolk, you can also pass the file once, and use getline to read it twice, but it's more longwinded and difficult to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using awk.

Loop the file twice.
For the first file increment the value of an array with key of `$2` by the value in $1 and then skip processing.
Print the line with the values from the array after $1.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]+=$1;next}{print $1"/"a[$2],$2,$3}' file file


1/3 book book
1/3 book is
1/3 book This
1/6 is book
2/6 is is
1/6 is pen
2/6 is This
```

Comment: great answer, how can I write it if scripting? BEGIN{
NR==FNR
}
{
count[$2]+=$1;next
}
END{print $1"/"count[$2],$2,$3} it's produce wrong answer after typing awk -f script file file

Comment: Literally paste the exact same command into a file. Why have you added BEGIN ?